# Why my url's are encoded in nginx.conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Basically I have this `nginx.conf` file where I receive some parameters from my `index.html` page form. One of these parameters is called `$url` and I use it to do a:

```
proxy_pass $url;
```

The thing is that the operation fails because the `$url` seem to be encoded and in my error.log file I see something like this:

```
[error] 18849#18849: *195088 invalid URL prefix in "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com"
```

However, if I hardcode the operation like this:

```
proxy_pass http://example.com;
```

or like this:

```
set $url_backup http://example.com
proxy_pass $url_backup;
```

it works without any problem.

How can I fix the URL issue ? Thanks

Comment: [Avoid nginx decoding query parameters on proxy_pass (equivalent to AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496963/avoid-nginx-decoding-query-parameters-on-proxy-pass-equivalent-to-allowencodeds) -- use a different parameter [Nginx variables - $request_uri](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri)

Comment: The thing is that I don't use the url from the browser, I use a url which is send by a form from my index.html page, from an input type text. See what I mean ?

Comment: What do you do to get that parameter? What did you try to resolve this? [set_unescape_uri](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_unescape_uri) could be a solution depending on what you do.

Comment: I tried with rewrite to replace %3A%2F%2F with :// but I get in some other error like my url becomes /etc/nginx/../http://example.com which is not a valid url anymore. set_unescape_uri I guess yes but this needs a new plugin and I was wondering if nginx can do this natively.